# What do we mean by "kavanah" in "mitzvot tzrichot kavanah"?

Tags: mitzvah, intent-accident-purposely

There is a halakhic concept of "mitzvot tzrichot kavanah," that you fulfill a mitzvah only if you had the intent to fulfill it.

What do we mean by "kavanah" here?
The intent to fulfill a commandment of God? Or just that doing this wasn't an accident or motivated by something else?

More to the point: Would an atheist Jew be able to have kavanah here? Or is belief in the divine source of the commandment required?

Comment: For your question about orthopraxy, see the 3 parshablog posts about this: https://www.google.ca/search?client=opera&q=parshablog+orthopraxy&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: see also http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Having_Kavana_for_Mitzvot

Comment: This is a fascinating question. I always wonder bout the mitzvas that specifically do not need kavana, such as tzedakah, mikvah immersion, and kriyas Shema (b'dieved) and how they are still "mitzvos" in this case. Also how this squares up with הכל בידי שמים חוץ מיראת שמים

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Mishna Berura discusses this in OC 60:7.  His conclusion is that the Kavanah required for "Mitzvos Tzerichos Kavanah" is to have in mind that you are fulfilling the Mitzvah as God commanded, as I bolded below.

> יש אומרים - דע דלפי המתבאר מן הפוסקים שני כונות יש למצוה א' כונת הלב למצוה עצמה **וב' כונה לצאת בה דהיינו שיכוין לקיים בזה כאשר צוה ד' כמו שכתב הב"ח בסי' ח' וכונת המצוה שנזכר בזה הסעיף אין תלוי כלל בכונת הלב למצוה עצמה שיכוין בלבו למה שהוא מוציא מפיו ואל יהרהר בלבו לד"א** כגון בק"ש ותפילה ובהמ"ז וקידוש וכדומה דזה לכו"ע לכתחילה מצוה שיכוין בלבו ובדיעבד אם לא כיון יצא לבד מפסוק ראשון של ק"ש וברכת אבות של תפילה כמו שמבואר לקמן רק שמחולקים בענין אם חייב לכוין קודם שמתחיל המצוה לצאת בעשיית אותה המצוה. ולמצוה מן המובחר כו"ע מודים דצריך כונה כדאיתא בנדרים ראב"צ אומר עשה דברים לשם פועלם ונאמר ותהי יראתם אותי מצות אנשים מלומדה וכמו שכתב הגר"א על הא דאיתא בסימן ח' עי"ש:

This is similarly echoed by Rav Eliezer Melamed in Peninei Halacha [here](http://ph.yhb.org.il/02-15-08/):

> ...שצריך גם לכוון בעת עשייתה שהיא נעשית לשם קיום מצוות הבורא...

Answer (score 2):

Regarding whether one can perform mitzvos without believing in the Metzaveh, a number of acharonim have argued that one cannot, due to a lack of kavanah. Their argument is that even according to the opinion which maintains mitzvos do not need kavanah, mis'asek or one who lacks all kavanah is not yotzei. See R. Hutner's Pachad Yitzchak on Pesach, pp. 53-54, as well as R. Elchanan Wasserman's Kovetz He'aros (in the section of Beiurei Aggados):

> נראה דכופר העושה מצוה אינה כלום דהוי מתעסק לפי מ"ש הר"ן בשם הרא"ה
>   דאפילו למ"ד מצות אין צריכות כונה והאוכל מצה בלא כונה יצא אבל דוקא
>   כשיודע שזו מצה והיום פסח ולא באינו יודע דאו הוי מתעסק והכופר אינו יודע
>   שהיום פסח ולא שזו מצה של מצוה, דלפי דעתו ליכא שום מצוה בעולם. מיהו נראה
>   דלפי מ"ש במ"מ דאכילה שאני שכן נהנה א"כ גם במתעסק יצא כמו בחלבים
>   ועריות וצ"ע בזה

Rabbi J. David Bleich, based on the Ramban's introduction to his commentary on Iyov, makes a slightly different argument:

> "Commandments, regardless of their intrinsic rationality, are binding and significant in the theological sense only because they constitute the fulfillment of a divine command. Thus, not only the existence of God but also the authenticity of revelation as a historical event and the divinity of the entire corpus of Torah are inherent even in those moments of Judaism which concern themselves with action and conduct rather than belief." - R. J.D. Bleich, With Perfect Faith, p. 3

The Netziv, in Haamek Davar Bamidbar 15:39, also states that one who performs mitzvot without belief has not fulfilled the mitzvah:

> ולא תתורו אחרי לבבכם - לימדנו בזה מעשה המצוות, **שלא נחשבו למצוה אלא
>   אם עושה ומאמין עכ"פ שהוא מצווה ועושה, לאפוקי אם לבבו פונה אחרי מינות
>   שאינו מאמין במצוה כלל, אין בעשייתו נחשב למעשה**, וזהו "אחרי לבבכם",
>   ופירשו בגמרא ברכות (יב,ב) "זו מינות".